Efficient way to store and retrieve big amount of data
I need to store a big amount of data (about 2.5 billion of new data rows per month), but also I need a very fast way to retrieve the latest value per group on specific time point. The data looking very simple:



ParameterId
Value
DateTime




1
12.5
2023-04-21 14:35:03


2
56.81
2024-03-01 16:21:17


1
12.5
2024-05-22 14:35:03


1
71.4
2024-05-31 18:27:03



For example, we need the latest values by each parameter on 2024-04-31 17:40. The result will be as follows:



ParameterId
Value
DateTime




1
12.5
2023-04-21 14:35:03


2
56.81
2024-03-01 16:21:17



This looks like it can be solved by a simple database storage, but I've some restrictions:

The disk storage is limited. That's why indexes cannot be used as it's almost an x2 of the data space
The max query time for any request is 5 seconds.
We have only 1 server

I've already tried to use TimescaleDB (table partitioning), but because I've only right datetime condition (<= dt) it's very inefficient to search for the value in old chunks from the first one.
Technically it's possible, because we have an old software developed by third-party company 10 years ago and it still working, but nobody knows how...

index (ParameterId, DateTime) the only solution. You can use clustered index (aka index organized table) to avoid storing copy of data

2.5B rows/mo means 1k rows/sec, right?

I think index should be avoided. Maybe I should store the latest value change for each hour in separate table and then use it in TimescaleDB condition to improve the performance? Or maybe I need another way to store data for fast search?

@the_it_guy  Without indexing each and every search will be performed by brute-force search i.e. VERY slow in case of billions of rows.

How many distinct parameterID are used?

About 15k parameters. With table partitioning the search will be performed only in specific chunks, isn't it?

Finally, we decided to use a MessagePack library. A block of 1000 entries was the most suitable for us (it's a compromise between reading and writing performance). Also MessagePack library supports compression. To find the needed block we have added a timestamp column with the block start write time.

You have different options to try to improve this solution.
First, if TimescaleDB with partitioning is inefficient for searching, you can try a different way for partitioning with smaller data sets. For example, if your partition is by day, try using by hour.
Another option is to try a different engine, InfluxDB for example (or maybe a columnar database?), to see if it works better with your workload.
Also, a good option could be adding a caching mechanism or in-memory database like Redis, as storage is a limitation. This will improve performance for your queries.
